# Antlr4 - Match empty set in lexer

Tags: set, antlr4

I just upgraded a project that was using the alpha version of ANTLR4 and matching an empty set worked fine. All that would happen was that ANTLR4 would throw a warning saying that it was matching and empty set.

Now using ANTLR language support 1.2.1 and parser generator 4.3.0 it now throws the error:
**"Error 1 '->' came as a complete surprise to me while matching a lexer rule"** in both places I require it to match an empty set.

Some of the code it breaks on:

```
mode FILE_MODE;
     ASCII: FASCII           -> mode( PATH_MODE );
     UTF8: FUTF8             -> mode( PATH_MODE );
     UTF16: FUTF16           -> mode( PATH_MODE );
     EMPTY_FILE_TYPE:        -> skip, mode( PATH_MODE );  // Throws the error on this line
```

How does one now match an empty rule?

Terry

Answer (score 1):

One does not.

The warning before indicates that Antlr was likely not generating functional code for that line.  If the grammar was working before, it was likely due to undefined behaviors in that particular Antlr version.

Now just remove the line.  Whatever was detecting the need to do a mode switch to `FILE_MODE` should determine to do so only if there is some file mode content to match. If not, then move on to considering if there is path mode content.

Determining the best mode plan/guard conditions is tricky. Sometimes the only solution is a predicate using lookaheads. To help further, exemplary source and the full relevant rule set is needed.

Comment: I think I have solved the empty set for the example shown but at the moment I can't compile due to another much more complicated mode that also needs an empty set to resolve. I might be able the break the mode into a series of fragments an then re-glue back the fragments back together as a much bigger fragment and then use the '?' operator.  But this requires a fragment to have the ability to change it's type thus. ** fragment MODIFIER_ID: FIDENT -> type( IDENT ); **. The compiler accepts the syntax but I have never seen it documented anywhere. So before I start modifying is the syntax legal?